# DRY controllers and views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Suppose, I have models `Article` and `Category` with HABTM relation. I can have different categories with names like `mobile`, `desktop` etc. I need list view for each category. For example `/mobile` path give me all `Articles` belongs to `Category mobile`, `/desktop` path give me all `Articles` belongs to category `desktop` and `/articles` path give me totally all `Articles`.  What is the best way to organize it (controllers, views, routes)? For each category create controller? But it's not DRY...and categories may be added by user later...

Comment: Have you read the Rails guide on [Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes:

```
get 'category/:type' => 'categories#index'
```

Controller:

```
def index
  type = params[:type]


  ## fetch categories based on type
  categories = Category.where(type: type)
end
```

The basic thing that you need to look here is the route. Only add one route, that can work for any number of category types

Comment: Right, that seems better. :)

Comment: But if we need in list view where all articles from all categories?

Comment: add `articles = Articles.where(:category_ids.in => categories.map(&:id))` in the index action. Also you need to explicitly handle the case to fetch all articles when the category type is `articles`

Answer (score 1):

No need to create additional controllers.

```
class ArticlesController
  def index
    @articles = case params[:type]
    when 'mobile'
      # .. select mobile articles
    when 'desktop'
      # .. select desktop articles
    else
      Article.all
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

Then in `routes.rb`

```
match "/mobile", controller: :articles, action: :index, type: 'mobile'
match "/desktop", controller: :articles, action: :index, type: 'desktop'

resources :articles
```